# MySQL character set for numbers compression

Tags: mysql, encoding, compression

I would like to store many numbers in 1 cell and save space. The idea is to encode each one to a string of a constant length and store them in a text field (presumably MEDIUMTEXT). What characters can be used so that they are 1 byte only? I assume that special characters are stored in a way that uses more than 1 byte. I can use e.g. base64 but I am not sure how many encoding characters I can add to the base before MySQL uses actually more space to store them than I manage to save.

Comment: You _hint_ that you want to use the string as an array and reach into it to pick out one "number".  Please be much clearer on that.  Also, how big can the "numbers" be.  Single digits?  temperature measurements?  GDPs?  Stock quotes?  Something else?  Why might "constant length" be beneficial?  I'll gladly focus on that if it is really necessary.

Comment: Exactly short GPS routes where there is redundancy in the repeating parts of coords. The idea is to separate longitudes and latitudes, find lows and highs of each to determine the range - to get the needed constant string length, then distract the low from each coordinate to get only the necessary digits, then encode them for compression and store the string, the low and the byte size. That should significantly reduce the DB size.

Comment: How much resolution in GPS?  How for do you move per step (min/max/average)?  In "middle" latitudes?  Or anywhere in the world?  Space is the most important issue, not cost of unpacking?

Comment: It is for sport activities tracking, so anywhere. resolution in meters. The idea is to store new data in a separate related table and after some time as it is not accessed a lot compress it to the same row with the activity and free the space in the related table gaining space of id, foreign key and encoded coords.

Answer (score 0):

You say "numbers". What do you mean, really?

- Digits?  See above.
- Integers?  (no decimal point, no fraction)
- Floats?  (with exponent, etc)

Some notes on digits, compression, etc:

- 1 byte per Ascii character -- 8 bits
- 1 byte per digit, since it is an ascii character
- One random digit, at maximum theoretical compression, is about 0.332 bytes.  Visualize it this way:  1000 is 3 digits and 1024 is 10 bits.
- MySQL's `DECIMAL` datatype puts 2 digits into one byte for smaller numbers; for larger numbers it stores 9 digits in 4 bytes.
- If you zip up a million digits of pi, it will come very close to the above compression.
- A simple Rule of Thumb is that "text" compresses 3:1.
- Base64 *expands* bytes by 8/6 because one 8-bit byte is represented by 64 (2^6) different characters.
- Base64 is more useful for avoiding special characters; it is not really a compression technique.
- A 4-byte MySQL `INT` (range of -2 billion to +2 billion, but usually just positive and not evenly distributed), when converted to base64 would take more than 5 bytes for 9-10 digits.

**General techniques**

**Client compression**:  For `123,2345,88,22`, here is one way to handle it.  In fact, I recommend this for virtually any text handling where compression is desired in MySQL.

1. use `compress()` (or similar function) in your client.
2. use `BLOB` (up to 64KB) or `MEDIUMBLOB` (up to 16MB) in the table
3. use `uncompress()` after retrieving the blob.

For an **array** of numbers, use `json_encode` for the array, then feed into compress+blob, above.  It will work for any sized "numbers" and provide nearly maximal compresssion.

You cannot *efficiently* reach into a `MEDIUMTEXT` or `BLOB` to get one number out of an array.  The entire cell will be fetched.

That leads to another general statement...  If you have a lot of stuff that you don't need to sort on, nor fetch individually, **JSON** is a good approach.  Think of it as *from MySQL's point of view* an opaque blob.  The application writes and rereads it as one big thing, then picks it apart.

The JSON will possibly encode the above example as `["123","2345","88","22"]`, which will be slightly fatter after compression.  But, any good compression algorithm will notice and take advantage of the repetition.

**Take advantage of the data**

```
17,22738 48,77795 300 
17,22792 48,77795 297 
17,22853 48,77764 294 
17,22874 48,77743 297 
17,22887 48,77704 300 
17,22968 48,77671 305 
17,23069 48,77563 296 
17,23092 48,77561 292
```

-->

```
17,22738 48,77795 300 
54 0 -3
61 -31 -3
21 -21 3
13 -39 3
81 -33 5
1 -108 -9
23 -2 -4
```

The numbers stay relatively constant.  Take advantage of it by starting with raw data, but then switching to deltas.  Try it will about 10 times as much data; I suspect you will continue to get better than 2x compression *before* zipping, but maybe slightly less than 2x after zipping.  (Zipping can take advantage of the repetition of `48,777`; I am taking more advantage of it by tossing most of it.)

Comment: I never tested the compress() function. It is for GPS, (please see my comment above). The point is that 4 bytes will be too much for most routes and the needed size may be different for longitudes and latitudes, if the route is along meridian or parallel. So I decided to encode the coords to string with the highest possible base, e.g. base128 gives 16384 for 2 bytes which is enough - 16 km route with 1 m precision and saving 50% storage memory. But how many different characters can I store in 1 MySQL byte and which field type is the best for this?

Comment: @TomášMoskala - Please provide a realistic example of the data (perhaps 100 bytes' worth), without worrying about compression.  That will help me tailor my answer toward what the raw data looks like.

Comment: lng lat alt
17,22738 48,77795 300
17,22792 48,77795 297
17,22853 48,77764 294
17,22874 48,77743 297
17,22887 48,77704 300
17,22968 48,77671 305
17,23069 48,77563 296
17,23092 48,77561 292
17,23125 48,7757 293
17,23156 48,77557 294
17,23167 48,77384 305
17,23185 48,77348 302
17,23233 48,77323 306
17,2328 48,77313 312
17,23333 48,77309 307
17,2342 48,77319 303
17,23529 48,77286 301
17,23663 48,77279 303
17,23714 48,77243 310
17,2373 48,77205 312
17,23742 48,77201 311
17,23791 48,77324 320
17,23869 48,77435 322
17,23887 48,77458 321

Comment: For example here the range of longitudes is about 1300 preserving all digits with delta=17,22658
so base64 would compress each to 2 bytes. If I could use base256 I would get the smallint range of 65535 which would be OK for majority of data so maybe use BLOB of SMALLINT and for more range BLOB of MEDIUMINT?

Comment: @TomášMoskala - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Sure but still this would entail id and foreign key and I need to pack it in one cell per coordinate set.

Comment: @TomášMoskala - I was assuming the 8 line sample would be all in a single cell.  (Whether newline is used or semicolon or even space is used does not matter significantly.  Space would compress slightly better, but forces the parser to count by 3s.)

Comment: So you suggest not to encode but just reduce and store the number in a TEXT cell?

Comment: @TomášMoskala - (1) do a programmatic shrinking of the data like I showed, plus (2) compress.  I got about 2x; compress gets another 3x; total = 6x.  Another thought:  capture only every second datapoint -- smaller data, but less detail on the tracking.